# Execute configuration bash script during docker build

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

During docker build I need to run a bash script, which sets up some environment variables.

The script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export ENVVAR=TEST
export HOST=local
export PORT=port
```

I try to call this script in my dockerfile in different ways but none of them are working. I tried these:

```
ADD ./myscript.sh
RUN chmod +x /myscript.sh;\
    /bin/bash -c 'source ./myscript.sh';\
    /bin/bash -c 'source /myscript.sh';\
    /bin/bash -c source ./myscript.sh;\
    /bin/bash -c source /myscript.sh;\
    source ./myscript.sh;\
    source /myscript.sh;\
    /myscript.sh;\
    ./myscript.sh;\

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Of course I only had one of these commands in my RUN and I just put them here grouped.

If I run the container and use `source ./myscript.sh` it works as expected.

Because of multiple restrictions and other reasons it is not possible for me to use docker compose, the -e argument, ENV KEY VALUE in dockerfile or similar approaches. I need to set up the environment variables during the docker build process.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply not sourcing the shell that is specified in your ENTRYPOINT. Just add your myscript.sh to your image (use COPY instead of ADD).

```
COPY myscript.sh /usr/local/bin
```

Then source it on the shell that is actually started by your entrypoint.

```
docker run myimage source /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
```

btw, myscript.sh is pretty non descriptive. You could use env.sh for instance.

Comment: thanks, but what can I do if I have an additional RUN afterwards with a shell script depending on the set environment variables? `RUN /configure.sh` <-- this depends on the environment variables set beforehand. having them not together is because of isolation and structuring reasons.

Comment: then source your shell before your run your configure.sh. Eg: `RUN source myscript.sh && configure.sh`